# android application public release issue

Tags: android

after finishing my android application development i used the command showing below to get private key, but it shows some errors such as "The Keystore was tampered with or password was in correct"

$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore DEBUG.keystore 
-alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

Is my problem with DEBUG.keystore?? Should i need to generate another keystore for public release??

Comment: Just export your project as a signed application in eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should definitely generate another key for public release (and keep it in a save place for future updates).

See http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#releasemode for details.

**EDIT:**

If you'r using Eclipse, use the ADT Plugin for Android to create your keyfiles and sign your application.

Comment: Mannaz, i generate new keystore and new unsigned application, but while running jarsigner it shows same error.i used the command shown below.                                                       $ jarsigner -verbose -keystore my-release-key.keystore 
my_application.apk alias_name

Comment: Are you prompted for your password? is the `alias_name` the same you gave when generating the key?

Comment: friends, finally i got the aligned apk file by doing as per the instructions provided http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/preparing.html#post-compile. but while installing, it shows some error. anybody any idea about the mistakes that i have done??

Comment: Probably you have an older version of the application installed which still has the old (corrupt & different) signature. Therefore android refuses to install the new one. Try uninstalling all previous versions.